# Copy specific Maven Build Artifact to Dockerfile using RegEx

Tags: bash, maven, cicd

Im building a Maven project where the `target` folder looks like this after the build has finished:

```bash
target
|____  my-application-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
|____  my-application-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
|____ my-application-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
|____ my-application-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
```

I want to dockerize this application and for that I am using a `Jenkinsfile` that is supposed to copy ONLY `my-application-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` to the directory of my `Dockerfile`.

I've build a RegEx that only catches the `my-application-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` but not the other JARs, but the problem is that `cp` does not support regular expressions.

Is there any way to copy files using the regular expression? Im using `bash`. I tried to use `find` and it works but it does not throw an error if no files were found. I definitely need a solution that throws an error in this case though.

Here is my solution so for that is executed by my `Jenkinsfile`:

```bash
sh """
find ./path/to/target -type f -regextype posix-egrep \
                    -regex './path/to/target/my-application-${versionRegex}\\.jar' \
                    -exec cp {} ./path/to/dockerfile \; 
"""
```

`versionRegex` is a variable defined as follows:

`def versionRegex = "[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{1,2}\\.[0-9]+(-(a[0-9]+-[0-9]{2}|SNAPSHOT|m[0-9]{2}|rc[0-9]{2}|[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*))?"`

Comment: Are you sure you need regex here? Wouldn't glob `my-application-+([0-9]).+(0-9).+([0-9])-SNAPSHOT.jar` do the job here?

Comment: What is `versionRegex`? Also you don't match `/path/to/target` in `-regex` just the filename

Comment: I updated my question with the definition of `versionRegex`. I'm not sure what you mean by "you dont match path/to/target in -regex" well i actually do and it works. Regarding glob: I don't think glob supports regular expressions but only glob expressions, right? I might be wrong here, but even then the suggestion you did is not sufficient unfortunately because our release version naming convention includes several different identifiers that all have to be matched. It can be `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, `1.0.0`, `1.0.2`, `1.0.2-rc01` etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Quickly answer

Copy all the target content and then delete the other files using simple bash commands

### Detailed answer

Build without docker or with another tool and the pass only the build result is not a common approach. You could build and runt the entire java application inside with docker using docker [multi stages](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/)

Any way I will list you some options

### Copy all and filter inside

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir /server
COPY target/* /tmp
RUN  cp /tmp/*SNAPSHOT.jar /server
RUN ls -la /server
```

Basically you need to copy all the target content to /tmp folder and then only copy from /tmp to /server the required jar

[image]

### Docker multi stage

Basically you could create a temporary image in which you have maven and everything required to build your java application. Then in another final image, you copy only the required jar from the previous image. The final image is light because only have the built jar, not maven , ant, etc

Here an complete Dockerfile to build and run a spring boot application

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk AS packager

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.5.2  
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
# set as env vars to be reused inside dockerfile and app instance....
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

# Install Maven and basic tools:
RUN apt-get update\
    && apt-get install -y curl\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven && \
    curl -fsSL http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 && \
    ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
# prepare local project folder structure:                           
ENV PROJ_DIR=/usr/src/app

RUN mkdir -p $PROJ_DIR
COPY . $PROJ_DIR

WORKDIR $PROJ_DIR

# first build of the project, to create a binary version for next build stage    
RUN ["mvn", "clean", "package"]

ENV BUILD_DIR=/usr/app
RUN mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR
RUN for i in `find $PROJ_DIR/target -name "*.jar" -print`; do cp -r $i $BUILD_DIR/app.jar ;done
RUN ls -la $BUILD_DIR

# THIRD STAGE: to package a release image with a smaller footprint     
FROM openjdk:8-jdk as installer  
 
ARG app_port=8080                                               
ENV app_port=$app_port                                           
EXPOSE $app_port                                                

# copy the app binaries from previous build stage:
COPY --from=packager /usr/app /usr/app
# plumb the entrypoint for prod container: 
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/usr/app/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex you could use GLOBs.

It maybe less familiar, but in this case you'll have built-in check for not found.

For your immediate problem you could use:

```
my-application-+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9])@(-SNAPSHOT|-rc01|).jar
```

Where:

- `+([0-9])` matches any number (>0) of digits. Like `\d+` in regex,
- `@(-SNAPSHOT|-rc01|)` matches any of `-SNAPSHOT`, `-rc01` or nothing. Like `(-SNAPSHOT|-rc01|)` or `(-SNAPSHOT|-rc01)?` in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Following work for the cases where you want to copy a file with name ending with a number:

my-application-"*[0-9]".jar